# Is this member variable used to register subclasses in this protype design pattern? If yes, how?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static-variables

I am studying this piece of code in the book "Design Patterns explained simply".

It is the implementation of proytpe design pattern by the author Alexander Shvets.

Although I thikn I have undrstand most of it, but the static variable `_landSatImage` have confued me for several days.

By the comment of the author, it seems to register the subclass.

**But how `_landSatImage` is used to register the subclasses?**

Anyone can give me some clue? Thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
//--------------------- 1 Image
enum imageType
{
  LSAT, SPOT
};


class Image
{
  public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    static Image *findAndClone(imageType); 
  protected:
    virtual imageType returnType() = 0;
    virtual Image *clone() = 0;
    // As each subclass of Image is declared, it registers its prototype

    static void addPrototype(Image *image) 
    {
        _prototypes[_nextSlot++] = image;  
    }
  private:

    static Image *_prototypes[10];     
    static int _nextSlot;  
};

Image *Image::_prototypes[];
int Image::_nextSlot;

// Client calls this public static member function 
// when it needs an instance of an Image subclass
Image *Image::findAndClone(imageType type)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < _nextSlot; i++)
    if (_prototypes[i]->returnType() == type)
      return _prototypes[i]->clone();
}

//----------------------- 2 LandSatImage
class LandSatImage: public Image
{
  public:
    imageType returnType()
    {
        return LSAT; 
    }

    void draw()
    {
        cout << "LandSatImage::draw " << _id << endl;
    }

    // When clone() is called, call the one-argument ctor with a dummy arg
    Image *clone()
    {
        return new LandSatImage(1); 
    }
  protected:
   
    // This is only called from clone()

    LandSatImage(int dummy)                                  
    {
        _id = _count++; 
    }
  private:
    // Mechanism for initializing an Image subclass - 
    // this causes the default ctor to be called, 
    // which registers the subclass's prototype

    static LandSatImage _landSatImage;
    // This is only called 
    // when the private static data member 
    // is inited
    
    LandSatImage()
    {
        addPrototype(this); 
    }
    // Nominal "state" per instance mechanism
    int _id;
    static int _count;
};

// Register the subclass's prototype
LandSatImage LandSatImage::_landSatImage; 


// Initialize the "state" per instance mechanism
int LandSatImage::_count = 1;

//------------------------------ 3 SpotImage

class SpotImage: public Image
{
  public:
    imageType returnType()
    {
        return SPOT;
    }
    void draw()
    {
        cout << "SpotImage::draw " << _id << endl;
    }
    Image *clone()
    {
        return new SpotImage(1); //
    }
  protected:
    SpotImage(int dummy)
    {
        _id = _count++;
    }
  private:
    SpotImage()
    {
        addPrototype(this);
    }
    static SpotImage _spotImage;
    int _id;
    static int _count;
};



SpotImage SpotImage::_spotImage;
int SpotImage::_count = 1;

//----------------------------------------- main 
// Simulated stream of creation requests
const int NUM_IMAGES = 8;
imageType input[NUM_IMAGES] = 
{
  LSAT, LSAT, LSAT, SPOT, LSAT, SPOT, SPOT, LSAT
};

int main()
{
  Image *images[NUM_IMAGES]; 

  // Given an image type, find the right prototype, and return a clone
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++)
    images[i] = Image::findAndClone(input[i]);

  // Demonstrate that correct image objects have been cloned
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++)
    images[i]->draw();

  // Free the dynamic memory
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++)
    delete images[i];
}
```

Comment: Well, it makes sense, to load the prototype only once, no? Could as well be implemented with a lazy loading Scott Meyer's Singleton for the prototype.

Comment: This is a rather wonky implementation. Why is a plain array used instead of a map? Why do they create a dummy image object with a special constructor just to register it? (CRTP could make the registration automatic) Why store a whole instance to clone it when a single function pointer is enough?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks.  For now, please ignore the reason why the author implemented in this way. Could you please explain how it is used to register subclasses?

Comment: The registration happens in `addPrototype()`, which is in turn called in the default constructors of the derived classes.

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. Is `_landSatImage` involved in registering subclasses? If yes, can you give more details.

Comment: Yes, its constructor performs the registration of the respective derived class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, I am a newbie of C++, why do we need `_landSatImage`? What if just don't include this variable when designing subclasses?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show some code of how you'd do it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. For example, what if I comment  out line `static LandSatImage _landSatImage;` and line `LandSatImage LandSatImage::_landSatImage;` ?

Comment: Its constructor will not be called, and nothing will perform the registration?